# Mismatch between C and Java bitwise operation on hex values

Tags: java, c, hex

I have the following line in a C code that claims to convert a signed int8 into unsigned int16.

```
float x = (float) (((int16_t) ((temp[0] <<8) & 0xff00) | (temp[1] & 0x00ff)));
```

I converted this for Java as

```
float x = (((temp[0] << 8) & 0xff00) | (temp[1] & 0x00ff));
```

For the same input array,

```
temp[] = {0xFC, 0x10}

x= -1008 // In C
x= 64528 // In Java
```

I referred on SO and google for various posts on this but could not identify what is missing.

Tried the other data types short, int, float etc but to no avail

How could we get the same value of -1008 in java? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your `int` type has 16 bits only, you invoke undefined behaviour. As a common rule, avoid shifting signed integers.

Comment: "claims to convert a signed int8 into unsigned int1". No it doesn't. It converts *two adjacent bytes,* apparently but not certainly of type `int8`, into a `float`. Correctly or otherwise as the case may be.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I was skeptical about the "claiming part" anyway

Comment: Rather, if `temp[0]` has a negative value, UB is always invoked, no matter the size of `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C you have one additional cast: `(int16_t)`. If you did the same in Java - `(short)`, you would get the same result.

The issue is that in both C and Java the temporary results are cast at least to `int` (or higher type which can hold the value). With cast to `int16_t` or `short` you force the compiler to lose the higher bits again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details of the issue. I certainly tried casting to `short` but it turned out that it was casting at the wrong place- issue with the brackets, my bad!